# cakephp: how to create relationship with 3 tables?

Tags: php, cakephp

cakephp: how to create relationship with 3 tables?
I have 3 tables..

```
Table 1 roles,
id
role_name: (admin, manager, staff..)

Table 2 modules
id
module_name (user module, Group module)

Table 2 actions
id
action_name: (edit, delete, list...)
module_id

Table 3 permissions
id
name:(all, owner right, group right, none)
```

I want to create relation between Tables Role, action & permission in cake php.
Say Role manager has 'owner right'(permission table) to edit action of User module.

Comment: Step one is to attempt something... _anything_.

Comment: here is the place to start : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html